# Inputfield information to image Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi everyone dose anybody know in what format data is generated in input field? What i really need to do is take information from input field and generate image with the same text.

Answer (score 0):

Its a string, to get it

```
string textToParse = gameObjectThatHasInputField.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
```

If you put resources in resource folder you can generate with Resources.Load

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html